# RCurl::getURL works, httr::GET has Failure when receiving data from the peer

Tags: r, httr, geturl, workday-api

I am building some functions to pull csv files from a website (in this case Workday) that requires basic authentication. I am noticing httr is not performing as expected

When I use the following,

```
httr::GET('https://wd5-services1.myworkday.com/ccx/service/')
```

I get this error

```
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
  Failure when receiving data from the peer
```

When I use

```
RCurl::getURL('https://wd5-services1.myworkday.com/ccx/service/')
```

I get the following (which is the result i want!)

```
[1] "500 : Invalid request"
```

My question is **why is httr erroring out, when RCurl (and cmd line curl too) is returning the proper http error?**

Comment: **update**. it looks like Worday updated their SSL cert. When i use `RCurl::getURL()` now I get a `error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure` 

but when i use `httr::GET()` I now get the correct result. 

So the `curl_fetch_memory()` error must have something to do with SSL ciphers.. I just don't know what.

Answer (score 0):

For me `httr:GET` works like expected. Anyway you can file a bug at github: https://github.com/r-lib/httr. Make sure to provide additional information like operating system.

```r
httr::GET('https://wd5-services1.myworkday.com/ccx/service/')
#> Response [https://wd5-services1.myworkday.com/ccx/service/]
#>   Date: 2018-09-23 11:09
#>   Status: 500
#>   Content-Type: text/plain
#>   Size: 21 B
```

<sup>Created on 2018-09-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: thanks I submitted the issue here https://github.com/r-lib/httr/issues/568